# Printing the string after a string in a string in java

Tags: java, string, replace, split, java.util.scanner

I have a txt file containing words and their abbreviations that looks like this

one,1

two,2

you,u

probably,prob
...

I have read the txt file into a string splitting it and replacing the commas with spaces like so..

```
    public String shortenWord( String inWord ) {
     word = inWord;
     String text = "";
     try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("abbreviations.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            text = text + sc.next().replace(",", " ") + " ";
        }
       // System.out.println(text);
        //System.out.println(word);

        if (text.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("nope");
        }

    }
     catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
         System.out.println( e );
    }
    return text;
 }
```

The user must input a word that they want abbreviated and it will return the abbreviated version of the word.

```
class testit{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Shortener sh = new Shortener();
    sh.shortenWord("you");
    }
}
```

I have it returning the word they entered if it is found but i want it to return the word next to it in the file which would be the abbreviated version.

eg. printed string 'text' looks like ..

```
one 1 two 2 three 3 you u probably prob hello lo
```

I want them to be able to enter 'you' the program find 'you' and then prints 'u' which is the next string over separated by a space

Comment: You could use an HashMap with key as the actual text and value as shorthand notation

Answer (score 0):

Removing the comma achieves nothing, so don't do it.

I would first split:

```
String[] text = sc.next().split(",");
```

Then compare with the first part of the split:

```
if (text[0].equals(word))
```

and if true, return the second part of the split:

```
return text[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the logic looks like below:

```
  Map<String,String> myShortHand = new HashMap<String, String>();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("abbreviations.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String text[] = sc.next().split(",");
        myShortHand.put(text[0],text[1]);
    }
```

Now get the details from map like

```
 myShortHand.get("one");
```